# What do you call a person who collects funds for a charity?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, if someone walked up to my home asking for me to donate to X cause on the behalf of Y group of people, what are they called?

Answer (score 2):

That's one definition of a [***solicitor***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/solicitor) Merriam has: 'an agent that solicits contributions (as to a charity)'

Answer (score 2):

At least in American English, *fundraiser* would do it—one who raises funds.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fundraiser

Comment: Fundraiser is used in Britain; solicitor means something completely different (a kind of lawyer).

Comment: We are accustomed to fundraisers in Britain. The term solicitor, while formally correct, would not be understood here by the majority of contributors, who understand solicitor as a legal person. That said, a fundraiser solicits donations.

Comment: The main meaning in AmE is a *project* that raises fund. There would have to be contextual clues for it to be understood as being a person.

Comment: No, it’s not the main meaning. It’s one of two. In any case, the question clearly refers to a person.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a more jocular term in use in the UK, namely 'charity mugger', sometimes shortened to 'chugger'. 'Charity mugger' would be understood by many (50%, at a guess), whereas 'chugger' is more restricted in use. 'Charity mugger' usually, but not always, goes hand in hand with the image of somebody wearing a hi-vis jacket with the name of their charity printed on the back and carrying a collection 'tin' (often made of plastic nowadays).

While the concept of mugging usually assumes that the mugged person (muggee!) is walking the streets rather than at home, you could certainly extend the use to e.g. "I just got doorstepped by a charity mugger". Along these lines, you could also say "charity doorstepper", which, though not widespread, would be well-understood and is rather accurate. This somewhat derogatory terminology is justified, I believe, given that many of these people specifically target the homes of well-off senior citizens, as I have learned from long observation in West London.